# Custom slug for User pod

Tags: wordpress, podscms

Is there a way to use a custom slug for an extended user table?
E.g. when adding a field "band_name" to the User table, I would like the details page to be available under /profiles/{band_name}/
Right now the only thing I get it the email address of the user account.

At the moment, the page /profiles/ is a WP page with a custom template "profiles.php" rendering a list of users via pods.
The detail page is a pods_page /profiles/* as I was unable to connect it automagically like I did with another custom content type "events", which takes the template "single-events.php" by default. "single-user.php" or "single-profiles.php" didn't work with the user pod.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register the template with the standard WP Template header like:

```
/*
Template Name: Profile Detail
*/
```

Then, select that template in your Pod Page settings.

Comment: I think this would have been the case if the pods name is "profile" but I'm working with an extended wp_users here. I was able now to get it working so that under /profiles/{username} there is the standard author.php displayed and I'm using that for displaying my profile information.